# command line application in JAVA to connect to MS SQL SEVER with Arguments

Tags: java, command-line-interface, console-application, command-line-arguments

I created a console application with a Menu System like this,

[image]

But since the requirement was different, I need to create a command line application, for example I need to connect to MS SQL Database so, I should do something like this :

[image]

If you see, I have a bat file, I will pass some arguments, any suggestion on how to start this development? I heard something called arg4j but not sure how to start with it.

Comment: If you use spring, see spring shell project

Comment: I have not used spring! Let me check out!

Comment: @deHaar Can you explain me a bit, I need to start from scratch, please tell me what things I need to study before I start.

Comment: I won't be able to explain that in more detail than it is explained in the answers to the question yours is a duplicate of. Just go to that question, read the answers and follow the links provided there. You will be able to do what you want if you read that carefully...